# How to position a slideshow?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently making my own website with the knowledge I am gaining through this course and came across a small obstacle. I do photography as a hobby and am making a website for my photography page. On the front of the page, I am trying to make a small slideshow (highlighted in the image below), however my slideshow is coming to the bottom of the page and is too big. I also included the code I wrote in HTML and CSS and was wondering if someone could guide me through to make this happen. Thank you so much for taking the time to read this!

Below is my code from my HTML file.

```
<div class="slide-container">
  <span id="slider-image-1"></span>
  <span id="slider-image-2"></span>
  <span id="slider-image-3"></span>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="Resources/img/r20.jpg" class="slider-image">
  <img src="Resources/img/r21.jpg" class="slider-image">
  <img src="Resources/img/r22.jpg" class="slider-image">
</div>
<div class="button-container">
  <a href="#slider-image-1" class="slider-button"></a>
  <a href="#slider-image-2" class="slider-button"></a>
  <a href="#slider-image-3" class="slider-button"></a>
</div>
```

Not sure how to show my CSS code so it would be nice if anyone could help me out here!

```
.slide-container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.image-container {
 width: 2400px;
 height: 600px;
 position: relative;
 transition: left 0.2s;
}

.slider-image {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.button-container {
  top: -20px;
  position: relative;
}

.slider-button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}

#slider-image-1:target~.image-container {
  left: 0px;
}

#slider-image-2:target~.image-container {
  left: -800px;
}

#slider-image-3:target~.image-container {
  left: -1600px;
}
```

I wanted the position of my slideshow (currently 3 pictures but want to add at least 8) to be on the front page on the bottom left corner, which unfortunately isn't showing up and it is showing up all the way to the bottom, with the image being enlarged.

Comment: Are you able to provide some sources that are close to your target state?

Comment: Hello, unfortunately I couldn't find the website that does what I want for mine, I do have an output of the website when I run it: https://imgur.com/gallery/0GglEAM First picture shows the front of the page with the turquoise color representing where I'd like the slideshow to be placed and the second picture is what I got (the slideshow does work, just not at the position I want it to be plus the white borders around it and the size!). I'm really sorry if I couldn't give enough information and will try my best if you need anything more!

Comment: Thank you for adding this very relevant example! Though I'm not an HTML expert, someone may be around to help you from here. Good luck and welcome to SO!

Comment: This doesn't seem like a [MCVE]

Comment: I apologize but I do not understand the statement and was hoping you'd explain it?